# Get absolute peak location in a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

Suppose I have the A matrix like this:

```
A =    [0,0,0,0,0,0,106,10,14,20,20,23,27,26,28,28,28,23,28,28,21,18,106,14,12,
17,16,15,22,19,20,18,21,23,23,18,17,15,106,28];

>>  plot(A)
```

I want the index of the peaks in this dataset.  The answer that I'm looking for in this example, is a matrix which contains those x value in your curve when you put the "data cursor" on absolute peaks.

The answer I want is: `K = [7 23 39]` which is the locations of the peaks.

When I use the `plot` command in MATLAB, the peaks are clearly visible.  How can I find the x value of absolute peaks?  Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not give you all the peaks, but it gives you the maximum value in the set:

```
max_locations = find(A==max(A))
```

If you want to find the peaks, use the findpeaks function:

```
[peakVal,peakLoc]= findpeaks(A);
```

Comment: @fatih_k,I've done what you recommend me in your answer, but it doesn't work in this case: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623427/max-locations-finda-maxa-command)

Comment: if you just find to find absolute peak location in a 2D array, then max_locations = find(A=max(=max(A))) can be called but for local peaks, findpeaks() is the right tool

Answer (score 0):

If you want maximum 5 or 10 peaks, use the following

```
[peakVal,peakLoc]= findpeaks(A,'sort','descend');
```