# Matlab, get the peaks in a vector, this does not work: max_locations = find(A==max(A))

Tags: matlab, matrix

In Matlab, I have the following matrix:

```
A = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,32,52,36,12,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,163,60,
21,31,34,35,38,38,40,38,38,40,34,37,39,34,32,32,33,31,39,40,37,36,24,39,162,
23,23,22,22,29,25,23,24,25,24,24,29,23,26,27,24,20,27,25,27,26,24,23,21,24,
162,20,24,29,30,28,25,31,28,30,32,35,29,31,32,30,29,30,30,31,31,30,30,29,25,
20,162,63,18,22,23,21,22,23,24,21,22,24,21,24,22,24,19,18,21,19,18,20,20,18,
20,13,162,162,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

My command is:

```
max_locations = find(A==max(A))
```

It returns 31, which is the index of the 31st element (the 163) which is the highest value in the list.

The answer that I'm looking for is max_locations = [31 57 83 109 135], which are the PEAKS.

Why is it not returning me all the peaks, and how can I do this?

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over again. If the first time got no response, then see why it had problems.

Comment: The answer to your other identical question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583989/finding-the-location-of-maximum-peaks-in-a-plot-with-matlab, already answers this. Use `findpeaks`.

Comment: he has 3 questions that are mostly identical, he kept asking because he didn't get an adequate solution.  Maybe a mod can consolidate the three into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the values at other locations are not maximum: 162 instead of 163.

```
>> L([31 57 83 109 135])
ans =
   163   162   162   162   162
```

If you want to find some extreme pickes you can try;

```
>> pick_location = find(L>160)
pick_location =
    31    57    83   109   135   136
```

To actually find peaks try [PEAKFINDER](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25500-peakfinder) submission from FileExchange.

Comment: And that makes it 10k! Congrats!

Comment: @yuk, but when I use plot(L) the absolute peaks are clear and they're location are [31 57 83 109 135]. that command should work for this case too.

Comment: @yuk, if I want to remove 136 in **peak location** what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: See the update in answer.